# Compiz and Mate and Lubuntu, GUI not responsive

Tags: lubuntu, gui

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS with mate desktop. When the graphic system starts, the topmost and bottom-most parts of the interface don't respond, only the middle part. To solve it, I use mate-tweak, then I choose any window manager and then the compiz. This way, everything works fine. But after reboot, the mess comes back again, so I need to run mate-tweak again and redo the configuration. What could be causing this? P.S: I'm using the undecorated maximized windows option from compiz.

Comment: Is it correct to say that you have 3 window managers installed and they appear to "not play well together"?

Comment: Maybe it is... but everything works normally, except that little quirk described in the question.

Comment: Have you tried going into LXDE's settings and setting which window manager is used by default?

Comment: I have entered "compiz ccp" on that setting, but it didn't work. Had to change it back to 'mate-session'

Answer (score 0):

Open "Default applications for LXSession" in Preferences
Click the "Autostart" tab
In "Manual autostarted applications", add the line "compiz --replace"